# Power external daughter board from Arduino only powered by USB?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, genuino

Been searching for an answer, but I see lots of talk about it, but not clear answers. Can somebody clarify this? If I power the Arduino only via USB, can I put a small daughter board? and power it from the Power connector(5V)

**Update:**

Thanks for the answers I'm using a Genuino UNO and it does power the daughter board my meter was kaputt, got a good one and it is fine even hooked a breadboard circuit to the 5V and GND and it works!!!

Comment: Probably the reason there is a lot of talk, but no clear answers, is that everyone has a different idea of what a "small" daughter board is; there is a limited power margin, and every LED, sensor or other add-on uses some power. The only true answer is "it depends on your specific situation".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. USB is limited to 500mA, the Arduino like an Uno has a 500mA fuse to protect the USB source.

The Arduino itself can use 25-50mA of that, or more depending on what you have connected to the IO pins.

Comment: note that USB3 officially provides almost an amp, while most computers and virtually all mains-usb "chargers" provide more than 500ma. Both apple and samsung "wall worts" for example provide 2 amps.